# Wordpress if else requirements for comments

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

I am not sure where to start, but I want to add in a symbol or change the css for the comments for registered users. Show a difference between non registered user comments and registered user comments.

How would I go about adding this to my wordpress website?

```
<div class="commentdetails">

<p class="commentauthor"><?php comment_author_link() ?></p>
<?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
<em>Your review is pending approval by gsprating staff.</em>
    <?php endif; ?>
<p class="commentdate"><?php comment_date('F jS, Y') ?>
&nbsp; &nbsp; IP/Hostname: <small>(coming soon)</small>
&nbsp; &nbsp; <?php edit_comment_link('Edit Comment','',''); ?>
</p>
```

I want to add make it so that the entire class is a different color if the user is a registered logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an all php version of Saladin's code using the standard if/else sysntax:

```
<?php
 if ($comment->user_ID) {
    echo "<div class='comment_registeredUser'>";
 }
 else { // The user is not logged in
    echo "<div class='commentdetails'>";
 }
?>
```

Putting all the code in php has fixed execution errors for me. Of course, that may have been because I was doing something else wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that could fix any execution problems, but the truth is that I made some pretty epic errors in my answer which would explain Bobby's problems. I've since cleaned up the answer and made it correct - probably shouldn't post answers at 3 in the morning, haha.

+1 for giving a much cleaner answer than I originally did.

Comment: Ok I tried implementing curts code, it appears no errors but does not use the class='comment_registeredUser'> for registered users comments. It still just uses the else. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Would it be easier to just enable gravatars and have it set to show the gravatar for registered users and not show for non registered? My overall goal here is, I have a gsp review website and I want my registered users to have some sort of special icon, color, etc... to show they are validated registered users.

Comment: If the value of the comments are equal regardless of user registration then it would make more sense to take another approach. My quick read about gravatars is that they're intended to be used across many sites. The registered user would have to have one in the first place. I would think a better approach would be to show a special avatar for non-registered users. In either case you still need to determine if the user is registered. Try reversing the class names just to see if the class definition works. Also, do you have a site for this that we could see?

Answer (score 0):

As comments are displayed in the `wp_list_comments()` function, you will need to edit the code there. The easiest way to achieve this is to use a simple if/else statement checking whether or not the comment has a user ID associated with it. If it does, that means the comment was made by a registered user.

Of course, as well as this, you will need to create a new CSS class to give the distinction. Here is some example code:

```
<?php if($comment->user_ID) : ?>
    <div class="comment_registeredUser"> <!-- Or whatever you decide to call the CSS class -->
<?php else : ?> <!-- The commenter isn't a registered user -->
    <div class="commentdetails">
<?php endif; ?>
// Then include the rest of the code as is
```

The `$comment->user_ID` variable will return a `true` if the comment poster is a registered user and was logged in when they posted the comment. The code above will assign your custom CSS class to the div if it does indeed return `true`. If not, it will simply apply the standard class and styling.

There is also a really good tutorial for developing themes over at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). Definitely worth having a read through if you are unsure on what you need to do to create/edit your WordPress theme.

**Edit:** Cleaned up the answer and better explained the *correct* logic.

Comment: How do I differentiate the div classes for non registered and registered?

Comment: I would create a separate div class for registered users. Something like `.comment_registeredUser` as an example. Of course, just adding a symbol is easier - append a symbol after one of the 'post info' strings.

Comment: Right, checkout the code I pasted in the original question. If I add <?php if ($user_ID) ?> to the top of that <div> class how would I differentiate between the two classes?

Comment: That didn't work, do I have to <?php endif; ?> anywhere? so that it doesn't continue to loop?

Comment: It changed all of the comments to that div css.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. Included the `endif;` to the code in my answer. Of course, you could have given it a try yourself. :) Remember that SO is a place to ask questions about specific problems you have, not to get people to write your code for you. :)

Comment: Understood ;) and that code didn't work the way I though it would. It added a <div> around my current <div> for the comments. So the background was a different color below the current comments. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Well, you want to make sure that the `<div>` end where it is supposed to. But the best thing for you to do, I think, is have a read of that tutorial in the WP Codex.

Comment: Updated answer, should be perfectly correct in terms of the code. Will update again later to fully rewrite the answer.

Comment: Here's another version of Saladin's code... Sorry, I forgot you can do carriage returns in comments. I'll do and answer.

Comment: Try `if($comment->user_ID != '0')` Just found an article here: http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Jalenack/Comment_Loop_Beauty

Comment: This WordPress plugin might be of use to you - probably won't need much, if any, coding: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2008/01/new-wordpress-plugin-bm-comment-highlight/